# Error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm creating my first Android App so I'm very new at it.  Everything has been going ok but now I'm getting an error.  The app is very simple.  Basically there is an activity with a question and 2 buttons.  Depending on the answer to the question you click one of the buttons that takes you to another activity.  Basically you keep answering question until you get to a final answer.

The point where I get the error was working before but now it crashes and I can't figure out why.

Here is the error:

```
02-28 18:45:42.969    1851-1851/c.whats_that_plane D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
02-28 18:45:42.970    1851-1851/c.whats_that_plane E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: c.whats_that_plane, PID: 1851
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{c.whats_that_plane/c.whats_that_plane.jtailtype}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Here is the code for the button I'm clicking

```
public class Propellers extends ActionBarActivity {

private static Button button_propellers;
private static Button button_jetengine;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_propellers);
    Gotoptailtype ();
    Gotojtailtype ();
}
public void Gotoptailtype () {
    button_propellers = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonyes);
    button_propellers.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent toptailtype = new Intent("c.whats_that_plane.ptailtype");
                    startActivity(toptailtype);
                }
            }
    );
}
public void Gotojtailtype () {
    button_jetengine = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonno);
    button_jetengine.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent tojtailtype = new Intent("c.whats_that_plane.jtailtype");
                    startActivity(tojtailtype);
                }
            }
    );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_propellers, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Specifically when I click the No button.  That calls this section of the code above.

```
public void Gotojtailtype () {
    button_jetengine = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonno);
    button_jetengine.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent tojtailtype = new Intent("c.whats_that_plane.jtailtype");
                    startActivity(tojtailtype);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

In the Intent if I replace the Activity c.whats_that_plane.jtailtype with c.whats_that_plane.ptailtype, which is then like clicking the yes button it will go to the ptailtype activity.  So there is something wrong when it's trying to call the jtailtype activity.

Everywhere I looked everything looks ok.  Manifest, Java and Activities.  Can someone give me an idea where I should look for what is causing this error or if you need more info.  Thanks.

Comment: Problem at `jtailtype` activity when you are trying to set `onClickListener()` to one of `Button or View` which is **NULL**.

Comment: Post `jtailtype` Activity code.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I understand it is NULL because it says that in the error message.  The issue is I don't know why it is NULL.  I can change the activity the button calls to ptailtype and it will go to the ptailtype activity but it's jtailtype it won't go to the jtailtype activity.  From what I can tell that means there is nothing wrong with the button but something must be wrong with the activity right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, something wrong in `jtailtype` Activity thats why I told you to post `jtailtype` activity code.

Comment: to get this right if you click the no button with a different intent it works okay, but if you do with this `"c.whats_that_plane.jtailtype"` it doesn't? i am asking that because i thinking problem is on the button you referencing.

Comment: @Elltz - This is not cause. The problem is seems to calling activity has some NullPointerException.

Comment: @user370305 thanks for confirming my thoughts and sorry I didn't see your comment about posting the jtailactivity code.  After looking at the jtailtype I found that I used the wrote button id in the following activity call.  Staring at the code everything starts to look the same.

Comment: @ToddAschenbrenner - Good. Happy Coding..:)

Answer (score 0):

Exception is occuring on this line

```
Intent toptailtype = new Intent("c.whats_that_plane.ptailtype");
                    startActivity(toptailtype);
```

Use this code to start different activity

```
Intent toptailtype = new Intent(Propellers.this,SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(toptailtype);
```

Also confirm that you are calling activity properly and activity you calling is not throwing any NPE.

Comment: This is not cause. The problem is seems to calling activity has some **NullPointerException**.

Comment: ok.. but it seems to be ""c.whats_that_plane.ptailtype" , user is calling only a package name here

Comment: Intent has overloaded constructors. Read the exception again: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference